# SwiftUI) Preview crashes when trying to open a sheet with the button on the Tool bar (Solved)

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

[image]

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isSheetShowing = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("hello")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button("add") {
                    isSheetShowing.toggle()
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShowing) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

When I add a button within the view and execute the same action, it works fine.
But when I run the code through the toolbar, the preview crashes.

What is the problem?

--------------------------Solved problem--------------------------

Now, as time passed, I ran the same project and the problem was resolved.

Comment: May be put the Button in a ToolBarItem will help

Comment: @PtitXav I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: This code is fine and is not causing the crash. I suspect something got corrupted. I would quit Xcode, removed the folder in DerivedData(Google it), and restart your computer. Sometimes things go sideways in the preview or simulator.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  It only affects Preview.  Simulator works fine.  If you use a button within the view to present the sheet, it will still crash if there is a button in the toolbar (even if the toolbar button has no action).

Comment: @Yrb I cleared the derived data and rebooted, it's still the same but thanks!

Comment: @P.Stern It's exactly what you said. Thank you.

Comment: @Yrb At first, I thought the crash was caused by CoreData. However, I cleared all the code, and the same problem occurred in a new project. Could it be that CoreData is causing a bug in Xcode? I am also using the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Just to clarify, the sheet opens once without crashing.  If I close the sheet and open it a second time, it crashes Preview.

Comment: @P.Stern Before I tell you the problem, have you had the same problem? And is it still unresolved and left as a bug?

Comment: @dukekim I have not experienced this problem myself.  I just used your code example.  I think you can report the problem to Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.

Comment: I have this bug on Xcode 14.3 as well, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Ok, It is crashing for me now. I would file Feedback to Apple using this example. This shouldn't break Preview.

Comment: I filed a bug report/feedback (FB12117330).  I don't think people can see each other's feedback, so I'll let you know if anything happens with it.

Comment: @P.Stern You are very kind. I'll be waiting. thank u

Comment: exactly what I see in my code, totally different code base, but same Preview crash when opening the sheet second time (first time is fine)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Went away when added `.navigationTitle("Title")` before the toolbar button.